# How can I play an intro video the first time I launch an iPhone app using swift (NOT objective-c)?

Tags: iphone, xcode, video, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to play an intro video for my iPhone app the first time it launches. I have it set up to detect that it's the first launch, but how do I play the video from the app (not a url) using SWIFT?  Do I set it up in the first ViewController file or in the AppDelegate? I've tried using MPMoviePlayerController, but I just can't seem to get it to actually play. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same trouble. Here's my solution:

```
func playVideo() {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType:"mp4")
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
        if let player = moviePlayer {
            player.view.frame = self.view.bounds
            player.controlStyle = .None
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.scalingMode = .AspectFit
            self.view.addSubview(player.view)
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to `import MediaPlayer` and declare your variable - `var moviePlayer: MPMoviePlayerController?`

Then call your function when you want to play it `playVideo()`

See my question for how to dismiss it - [In iOS how do I programmatically add a video view and then remove it after it finishes playing using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524064/in-ios-how-do-i-programmatically-add-a-video-view-and-then-remove-it-after-it-fi)
I got a really helpful answer there.

Also notice that I disabled my controllers because I don't want it to be seen.