# In iOS how do I programmatically add a video view and then remove it after it finishes playing using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, video

I'm trying to make a little intro video for an app before you land on the main view. Code as follows:

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var moviePlayer: MPMoviePlayerController?
    //var player: MPMoviePlayerController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        playVideo()
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func playVideo() {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("paint-me_intro", ofType:"mp4")
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
        if let player = moviePlayer {
            player.view.frame = self.view.bounds
            player.controlStyle = .None
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.scalingMode = .AspectFit
            self.view.addSubview(player.view)
        }
    }
}
```

All I want it to do is after the video finishes playing, it needs to go away. That's all. Any help would be greatly appreciated before I smash my face against the wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MPMoviePlayerController uses notifications for message passing, unlike the delegate/protocol pattern of so many other classes.  Regardless, to answer your question.  Add an observer for the appropriate notification in your view did load, and point to a function which removes the view.

Adding observer

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "movieFinished", name:
        MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification, object: nil)
```

And the function to remove it.

```
func movieFinished() {
    moviePlayer!.view.removeFromSuperview()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification, object: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I knew how to do it in C but couldn't seem to get it to port well. Do I have to call the function anywhere or just let it run?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. I didn't realize how dumb that question was. Thank you so much for that little tidbit. I've been working on this for over a week and now it's all beautiful again! Kudos!